# java.lang.VerifyError: class org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.ArrayType overrides final method isAbstract.()Z

Tags: java, json, verifyerror

I am getting this error when I am deploying an application

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.ArrayType overrides final method isAbstract.()Z
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
```

The interesting point is, the same application is deployed in another machines and running fine.
What's wrong with this? Seen lot of questions and understood the point in the problem/java throwing. But what should I do to solve this issue for this case, is unknown.

Please help me out

Comment: Check Java version for both machines.

Comment: @Dmytro, they are same

Comment: Did you build you application separately on each machine?

Comment: @Dmytro, no. we have common jenkins job

Comment: Are you able to build it yourself to find out if there are no bugs with the Jenkins job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the problem is solved by replacing Tomcat version to 7.0 instead of 6.0
I just copied the tomcat from another server to the server where I had problem and everything went fine after that. Bit weird though :-/

Answer (score 2):

You use a jar file which contains `ArrayType` which tries to override a method `isAbstract()` which is declared `final` which means it cannot be overridden which makes the bytecode verifier to throw a `VerifyError` exceptin.

The problem is that you are mixing jars having different versions.

`ArrayType` inherits from  `org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBase` which inherits from `org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType`.

`JavaType` is where `isAbstract()` is defined. In older versions it is declared as:

```
public final boolean isAbstract() {
    Modifier.isAbstract(_class.getModifiers());
}
```

Which is **`final`** as you can see which means you cannot override it. In a later version this was changed to

```
public boolean isAbstract() {
    Modifier.isAbstract(_class.getModifiers());
}
```

**`final`** has been removed later on (in a later version) which allows subclasses to override this method. You use a version of `ArrayType` which was built on newer versions of `JavaType` but your included jar is an old version when this was not allowed.

You must use the same versions from all jars and then this will work, you will not get this exception. For example copy all dependencies (jars) from the machine that does work and contains the jars with the proper versions to the other computer where you get the `Exception` (where you have other, older versions of your dependencies).

Or simply download the latest Jackson jars from the [download page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) and use those everywhere.

Comment: I would agree with you. But the same application is running on different machine with same JDK version. Why it doesn't run on this machine

Comment: Because the referred classes might come from jars either being part of the (web)application or being part of the environment (e.g. the JDK, servlet container like Tomcat etc.). If the referred class is part of the environment, it might be loaded from there and not from your application even if your app contains the proper version.